# How to Use RegEx for Sheet Names in Excel?

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I'm trying to duplicate a sheet. The user inputs the sheet name with an Input Box.

I'm trying to figure out how to interrupt the process if the user inputs a sheet name that already exists.

My plan is to use RegEx to match the string against all of the sheets in the workbook, and determine if the inputted name is already in use.

Here is my current code:

```
Dim NewSheetName As String

SheetInput: NewSheetName = InputBox("Insert the new sheet name.")

  'Ends procedure if user does not input anything.
    If NewSheetName = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

  'Ends procedure if the sheet name is already in use.
    Dim RegEx As Object
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With RegEx
        .Pattern = NewSheetName
    End With

    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        If RegEx.Test(Sheet(i).Name) = False Then
            MsgBox ("This name is already used on a different sheet.  Please use a different name.")
            GoTo SheetInput
        End If
    Next i
```

I get the message

> "Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined"

with Sheet in `Sheet(i).Name` highlighted.  I assumed the name of the sheet would be inputted into the RegEx function as a string, but this doesn't seem to be happening.

Comment: It should be `Sheets(i)` and it should be `= True` but you don't really need regex for this. A simple string comparison would do the job.

Comment: There's no `Sheet` collection but there's a `Sheets` collection.

Comment: Changing Sheet to Sheets and False to True solved the problem.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to check if a sheet exists. Here is one. I am sure there may be better ones.

```
Public Function worksheetExists(ByVal wb As Workbook, ByVal sheetNameStr As String) As Boolean

On Error Resume Next
worksheetExists = (wb.Worksheets(sheetNameStr).Name <> "")
On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Here are a couple of ways to call this function:

```
If worksheetExists(ThisWorkbook, "sheetNameOne") then ...

If Not worksheetExists(ThisWorkbook, "sheetNameOne") then ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a call to a couple of user defined functions that are reusable, and restructuring your code to use a `Do Loop` instead of `GoTo` see the following:

```
Public Sub AddNewWrkSht()

    Dim SheetName As String

        SheetName = GetValidSheetName()

    Dim NewWrkSht As Worksheet
    Set NewWrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        NewWrkSht.Name = SheetName

End Sub

Private Function GetValidSheetName() As String

    Dim NewSheetName As String

        'keep asking the user for a valid sheet name
        'until it is valid
        Do
            NewSheetName = InputBox("Insert the new sheet name.")

        Loop Until IsValidSheetName(NewSheetName)

    GetValidSheetName = NewSheetName

End Function


Private Function IsValidSheetName(ByVal SheetName As String) As Boolean

    If IsValueEmpty(SheetName) Then
        MsgBox "You must Provide a sheet Name."
        Exit Function
    End If

    If WorkSheetExists(SheetName) Then

        MsgBox "This name is already used on a different sheet. " & _
               "Please  choose a different name."

        Exit Function
    End If

    'if we make it here without exiting, then the sheet name is valid
    IsValidSheetName = True

End Function

Private Function WorkSheetExists(ByVal SheetName As String) As Boolean
   On Error Resume Next
   WorkSheetExists = Not ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName) Is Nothing
End Function


Private Function IsValueEmpty(ByVal varValue As Variant) As Boolean
    IsValueEmpty = (Len(RemoveAllWhiteSpace(varValue)) = 0)
End Function


Private Function RemoveAllWhiteSpace(ByRef varStringIn As Variant, _
                                     Optional ByRef RegExpIn As Object) As String

    'Create if not instantiated
    If RegExpIn Is Nothing Then Set RegExpIn = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With RegExpIn
        .Pattern = "\s"
        .MultiLine = True
        .Global = True
        RemoveAllWhiteSpace = CStr(.Replace(varStringIn, vbNullString))
    End With

End Function
```